# Asyncio await coroutine not returning value

Tags: python, python-asyncio, yahoo-finance

I am learning Python here with asyncio. I have a Javascript background and am expecting it to work similar to js.

Unfortunately, it says that my coroutine does not have the columns from the chain data frame in the code that proceeds this excerpt. My impression is that it is not awaiting correctly.

```py
async def get_chain(symbol):
    try:
        chain = await options.get_options_chain(symbol, req["expiration"])
        return chain
    except Exception as err:
        print(err, flush=True)

async def get_price(symbol):
    try:
        price = await si.get_live_price(symbol)
        return price
    except Exception as err:
        print(err, flush=True)

@app.route("/dev/api/option/rankings", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin(origin="*")
async def get_option_rankings():
    # get saved db symbols
    req = request.get_json()
    arr = []

    for symbol in req["symbols"]:
        # get stock price
        chain = get_chain(symbol)
        price = get_price(symbol)

        print(chain, flush=True)
        print(price, flush=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure which framework you're using, but in fact you AREN'T returning anything from `get_option_rankings`.  Don't `print` your results, return them as a string.

Comment: You’ll also have to await `get_chain` and `get_price`.

Comment: I assume this is Flask

Comment: Yes this is Flask

Comment: @TimRoberts theres proprietary code that is in the full api route that is not for public consumption that indeed does a lot of other things and returns data.

Comment: @dirn when I awaited those it still returned a coroutine. I was wondering if there was a special thing needed to do perhaps because it is using yahoo fin instead of a more standard request?

Comment: `get_chain(symbol)` will return a coroutine. `await get_chain(symbol)` will schedule the coroutine returned by `get_chain` and wait for it to complete, returning any value returned by that coroutine. That value could happen to be a coroutine; we don’t have enough code to tell.

Comment: @dirn the calls are made through the yahoo_fin package. I did not define the options.get_options_chain or si.get_live_price. In testing it seems no matter what I do it returns a coroutine. I was hoping it would be built in such a simple way like in JS where awaiting resolves the async nature and your done.

Comment: I think I will try Trio as an alternative to Asyncio. All I want is async await. Nothing more. I think this newer package might do what I am looking for. Since no matter how many times I await in asyncio it just returns coroutines. Seems ineffective for such a simple syntax ask like in JS. https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html